# Spyder in WinPython can't connect to kernel

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, windows-10, spyder

I am using a fresh install of WinPython 2.7, which includes Spyder 3.0.0, on Windows 10. When I start Spyder, the ipython console never connects to the kernel.

I have tried resetting spyder through the WinPython command prompt (spyder --reset&&spyder) and regular command line (spyder --reset) and tried opening multiple ipython consoles without any luck. There are no errors in the kernel tab. I have made sure that Spyder is pointing to the correct python.exe in WinPython.  I have made sure the qtconsole is installed. Ipython QT console built into WinPython works fine.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

what is your path to winpython ? spaces or unicode characters may trouble Spyder.
Otherwise try with a previous, or posterior  version of WinPython

Comment: Path is C:\Winpython so that shouldn't be a problem. Was hoping to avoid having to use a different version, but if I don't find a solution, then I will concede to that.

Comment: may be your C\Winpython is read only, or this particular place is worying Microsoft antivirus. Would you mind moving it to c\users\JeffLapierre\documents ?

Comment: Interesting idea, but sadly that didn't work. Also, I tried WinPython 3.4 and am still having the same problem.

Comment: well, last suggestion is to retry after a reboot. and maybe disconnected from any network ?